# Generate a set of pairs

Tags: probability-or-statistics

I am dealing with the following function

```
fun[x_, z_] := a (1 - z^2) cos[x]^2 - (b z^2 + z - c).
```

My task is to generate the set of random pairs {x, z} such that the relation fun[x, z] > 0 holds. a, b and c are real numbers, -1 < z < 1 and 0 < x < 6.
Any suggestion would be very much appreciated.

Comment: And do you want to choose these pairs *uniformly* in the relevant region?

Comment: No, it can be random either.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand your comment. You could just choose a point uniformly (if that's the distribution from which you're pulling, which I assume) in the region specified be your inequality and check whether or not it satisfies `fun[x,z] >0`. If so, keep it. If not, throw it out. This is called rejection sampling (or the accept-reject Monte Carlo algorithm).

Comment: In case the point is uniformly, could you please help me to write an appropriate code

Answer (score 5):

The function is given by

```
fun[x_, z_] := a (1 - z^2) Cos[x]^2 - (b z^2 + z - c)
```

We define a function that generates a random point in the `x`-`z` plane that satisfies `fun[x, z] > 0`:

```
accept[a0_, b0_, c0_] := 
  Block[{a = a0, b = b0, c = c0, x = RandomReal[{0, 6}], z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}
    , If[fun[x, z] > 0, {x, z}, accept[a, b, c]]
   ]
```

**Important note**: this definition is dangerous, because it is recursive. You should make sure that there are actually a good number of `x`-`z` pairs that satisfy `fun[x, z] > 0` first before using this definition, because it runs the risk of running into the `$RecursionLimit`. As it is, it randomly generates a point, and if it satisfies the condition, it keeps it, and if it doesn't, then the function calls itself. Thus, it will eventually spit out a point if there is one to be found (or rather, if acceptable region is not too small).

Alternatively, you can define this function with a so-called "vanishing function" (named `Nothing` in *Mathematica* 10.1 and later) as

```
acceptReject[a0_, b0_, c0_] := 
  Block[{a = a0, b = b0, c = c0, x = RandomReal[{0, 6}], z = RandomReal[{-1, 1}]}
    , If[fun[x, z] > 0, {x, z}, ##&[]]
   ]
```

This will return literally nothing if the point doesn't satisfy the condition, and so when you make a `Table` of points, you will get only a list of points that satisfy the condition. However, the list of points won't necessarily be as many points as you specify, because it doesn't try to find another point if the random point that it chose doesn't fit the criterion; rather, it just moves on.

That said, we can generate a table of points via

```
points = Table[accept[3, -2, -2], {500}];
```

and we can plot the function along with these points to make sure that we are generating a uniform sample from the region:

```
Show[
 Plot3D[Evaluate[fun[x, z] /. {a -> 3, b -> -2, c -> -2}]
  , {x, 0, 6}, {z, -1, 1}
  , RegionFunction -> Function[#3 > 0]
  , Mesh -> None
  , PlotStyle -> Opacity[0.3]
  ]
 , Graphics3D[Point[{##, 0} & @@@ points]]
 ]
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

```
fun[a_, b_, c_, x_, z_] := a (1 - z^2) Cos[x]^2 - (b z^2 + z - c)
reg[a_, b_, c_] := 
 ImplicitRegion[
  fun[a, b, c, x, z] > 0 && -1 < z < 1 && 0 < x < 6, {x, z}]
```

Visualizations (using triple {3,-2,2} used in another answer):

```
rp = RegionPlot[reg[3, -2, -2]];
cp = ContourPlot[fun[3, -2, -2, x, z], {x, 0, 6}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   Contours -> {{0}}];
p3 = Plot3D[fun[3, -2, -2, x, z], {x, 0, 6}, {z, -1, 1}, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &}, Mesh -> {{0}}];
Row[{rp,cp,p3}]
```

[image]

You can generate a list of random points for a given {a,b,c} using `RandomPoint` for region:

```
ListPlot[RandomPoint[reg[3, -2, -2], 1000, {{0, 6}, {-1, 1}}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I am thankful for you code.

Comment: Hello ubpdqn. Let me thank you again for your nice code. I tried to plot the reg function defined above using PolarPlot function but with no luck. Could you please help me in this? Thank you in advance.